# How to type hint a function that transforms an RDD?

Tags: pyspark, rdd

Given a StructType schema I want to be able to define

```
def foo(row: schema)
 return row.field
```

and have PyCharm recognize the fields of row, but PyCharm does not recognize 'schema' as a type. Inlining makes no difference. (I'm using Python 3.8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not technically correct; row is a Row, but it works just fine thanks to duck typing:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class HintedRow:
  x: int
  y: str

def foo(row: HintedRow):
  return row.x

df.rdd.map(foo)
```

Now you can use it in unit tests like so and pyspark will not complain because HintedRow's properties are the same as those of the Row:

```
test_row = HintedRow(x=1, y='bar')
assert foo(test_row) == 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you wanted to specify type hint as `StructType`?

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType

def foo(row: StructType):
    return row.field
```

Comment: That's a generic StructType; it does not know if it has 'field'.